# How to return ID of student who used ban word in text message (Updated)

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe

```
 ID_Student                    Text_Message
1   John Doe Hell like I want to fxxk around
2 Peter Gynn                 You such an ass
3 Jolie Hope                      Go to hell
```

And I have vector

```
> Ban_words
[1] "fxxk" "ass"  "hell"
```

How to return ID of a student who used any of the ban words with the words that they used?
Any ideas?

My solutions so far.

Data

```
ID_Student <- c("John Doe", "Peter Gynn", "Jolie Hope", "Mike Tyson")
Text_Message <- c("hell I want to fxxk around", "You such an ass", "Go to hell", "I love you")
Ban_words <- c("fxxk", "ass", "hell")
Student_Message <-data.frame(ID_Student,Text_Message)
```

Dataframe should looks like this

```
ID_Student               Text_Message
1   John Doe hell I want to fxxk around
2 Peter Gynn            You such an ass
3 Jolie Hope                 Go to hell
4 Mike Tyson                 I love you
```

Code

```
for (i in Ban_words){

Detention_List<-Student_Message %>% filter (grepl(i, Text_Message))%>%
        pull(ID_Student)
print(Detention_List)

}
```

Which returns

```
[1] "John Doe"
[1] "Peter Gynn"
[1] "John Doe"   "Jolie Hope"
```

So, for the band word 'fxxk', only John used it. But for the word 'hell', both John and Jolie used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can collapse all the "Ban_worsd" into a single regex with `paste(collapse = "|")`, then use grepl with this regex to filter the dataframe. Then `pull` the vector with the names. As you can see, this returned the names of all students but "Mike", as he did not use the ban words (see my edited data).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter (grepl(paste(Ban_words, collapse = '|'), Text_Message)) %>%
        pull(student)

[1] "John Doe"   "Peter Gyn"  "Jolie Hope"
```

**data**

```
df<-data.frame(student=c('John Doe', 'Peter Gyn', 'Jolie Hope', 'Mike'), Text_Message=c('I want to fxxk around', 'You such an ass', 'Go to hell', "I love you"))

> df
     student          Text_Message
1   John Doe I want to fxxk around
2  Peter Gyn       You such an ass
3 Jolie Hope            Go to hell
4       Mike            I love you

Ban_words<-c("fxxk", "ass",  "hell")
```

Comment: Thanks! I figure it out you somehow have to use grepl. Been learning R slowly based on my research requirement. The ID is actually protein ID and the text message is actually the protein sequence while the ban words are actually short sequence list I want to detect in the protein sequence.

Comment: Also, you can learn how to manipulate strings with the `stringr` package. I think it is much more intuitive than base R. I this case, we could use `str_detect()` instead of `grepl()`
https://stringr.tidyverse.org/